# how to use mod_rewrite or url remapping for assets folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

was hoping you could help me out

I have an 'assets' folder in codeigniter on which I want to use mod_rewrite. Note that this 'assets' folder is not in the 'application' folder, i.e the structure is similar to:

```
/codeigniter-installation-root
        /application
        /system
        /assets
```

*(I think)* This means that I cannot use the 'routes.php' in the codeigniter config for routing.

Issue is that my .htaccess in the assets folder is not working.

To confirm it isn't working I tried this structure:

```
/root
        ...
        /assets
            /test
                np.php
                .htaccess
```

the contenst of **.htaccss** are

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^empty.php$ np.php
```

but it isn't working. if I go to the url **base/assets/test/empty.php** I get a 404 error. Copying this 'test' folder to some other directory on my localhost works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just use assets folder (NOT for assets only?).

Comment: yup... like Kyslik mentioned, what are you trying to achieve here?
codeigniter will look for php files inside your application/views forlder? the routes.php file will stipulate the homepage / or main start page to your application! assets folder should be used for javascript, images, etc... all other php files should be welded into your application, using the model/view/controller/ fodlers!

Comment: Basically I was trying to create a versioning system for my asset files (javascript, css, etc) without using the get query parameters (i.e foo.js?version13). So I thought I would do it by remapping through htaccess (i.e remap asset/v13/something to assets/something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the .htaccess to the root of the codeigniter installation with the following code, or any other similar code, that allows the removal of index.php from the URL and remove the index.php from the config file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|system|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Now, the .htaccess in the assets sub-folders should work.